# Chaining HTTP call in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, rxjs

I'm trying to get Google Places with their API and get a response body that contains a "photo_reference" property. With this property, I want to get the Google Place Image and call a second API.

I have an input field that can search for places. By entering a string and clicking on the search button, this method will get called:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  private lng: number;
  private lat: number;
  private place_id: string;
  private listOfPoi: GoogleLocation[];

  constructor(
    private gs: GoogleService,
    private ds: DataService,
    private router: Router
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ds.getLocation().subscribe(loc => this.listOfPoi = loc);
  }

searchPoi(location: string): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/poi']);    
    this.gs.getPoi(location).pipe(
      map((response) => response)
    ).subscribe((data: GoogleResponse) => {
      if(data.status === "OK") {
        this.ds.setLocation(data.results); //data.results is an array of locations
      }      
    });
  }
```

In my other component, I try to get the locations and map them into a new object with the property imgUrl.
I want to save them in an array.

```
export class SightseeingViewComponent implements OnInit {
  listOfPoi: LocationWithImage[];

  constructor(private ds: DataService, private gs: GoogleService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ds.getLocation().subscribe(
      (loc) =>
        (this.listOfPoi = loc.map((loc) => {
          return {
            ...loc,
            imgUrl:            
            this.gs.getImage(loc.photos[0].photo_reference).toString(),
          };
        }))
    );
  }
}
```

But my problem is the `img src="[object Object]"` it should be the string!

**My problem is this line `this.gs.getImage(loc.photos[0].photo_reference).toString()`**
I tried to replace this line with a random hardcoded img Url and it works. The image are shown but I cannot retrieve the URL as string with this method.
Of course toString() is not working but I have no clue what else I can do?

This is the google location model:

```
//The model of a google location object from the API response (getLocationInfo)
export class GoogleResponse {
    constructor(
        public results: GoogleLocation[],
        public status: string
        ) {}

}

export class GoogleLocation {
    constructor(
        public formatted_address: string,
        public geometry: Locations,
        public icon: string,
        public name: string,
        public photos: PhotoInfo[],
        public place_id: string,
        public reference: string,
        public type: string[]
    ) {}
}

export interface LocationWithImage extends GoogleLocation {
    imgUrl?: string;
}
...
```

EDIT:

This is my service:
With this, I make a call to my backend which is fetching the photo_reference from Google via its API

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GoogleService {
  url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getLocationInfo(location: string): Observable<GoogleResponse> {
    console.log(location);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    });
    return this.http.post<GoogleResponse>(
      this.url + 'googleplace/',
      { name: location },
      { headers: headers }
    );
  }

  getPoi(location: string): Observable<GoogleResponse> {
    console.log(location);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    });
    return this.http.post<GoogleResponse>(
      this.url + 'googlepoi/',
      { name: location },
      { headers: headers }
    );
  }

  getImage(photoRef: string): Observable<string> {
    console.log(photoRef);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    });
    return this.http.post<string>(
      this.url + 'googlephoto/',
      { photoRef: photoRef },
      { headers: headers }
    );
  }


}
```

Here is my other service which is needed to send and retrieve data from other components

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private googleLocationSource = new Subject<GoogleLocation[]>();

  constructor() { }

  public getLocation(): Observable<GoogleLocation[]> {
    return this.googleLocationSource.asObservable();
  }

  public setLocation(gl: GoogleLocation[]) {
    return this.googleLocationSource.next(gl);
  }
```

Comment: Presumably getImage returns an *observable* of the data, and it's unclear why you thought toString would magically make it synchronous. Please give a [mre].

Comment: Yeah I know... How can I get the string value of that? I tried with pipe, forkjoin, map, switchmap and so on but not working.. Okay! I provided more information, does that help?

Comment: It's unclear what you've tried, I'd expect `forkJoin` to work (given you want to fan out to multiple observables then get all of the results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is this line `this.gs.getImage(loc.photos[0].photo_reference).toString()`

Yes, calling `toString()` on an observable isn't going to work ! :-)

You need to subscribe to that observable to receive its result.  There are a few "[Higher Order Mapping Operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)" that can do this for you, so you don't have to deal with nested subscriptions.  In this case, we can use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap).

However, it's a little more complex because you want to make a call for each element in the returned array.  We can map each location to an observable call to get the image and use [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) to create a single observable that emits an array containing the results of the individual observables:

```js
this.ds.getLocation().pipe(
  switchMap(locations => forkJoin(
    locations.map(loc => this.gs.getImage(loc.photos[0].photo_reference))
  )
  .pipe(
    map(imgUrls => imgUrls.map(
      (imgUrl, i) => ({ ...locations[i], imgUrl })
    ))
  ))
)
.subscribe(
    locations => this.listOfPoi = locations
);
```

The flow here is:

- `switchMap` receives the locations and subscribes to observable created by forkJoin
- `forkJoin` creates an observable that will emit an array of the results (image urls) from all the individual `getImage()` calls.
- `map` receives the array of image urls and maps it to an array of locations that include the image url
- subscribe simply receives the final array

Comment: I see thanks. Indeed I want to call for each element, so it's a bit complicated. I tried your solution but it says that `locations.map` is of type `unknown` also `Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown[]>'.` `this.ds.getLocation()` will return an Observable from type GoogleLocation[] btw

Comment: I added some more information, I don't know if they help.. Thanks again

Comment: looks like I had a misplaced paren.  updated!

Comment: Thank you a lot! It seems to work and no error!! Just getting CORS problem now but this is another problem:) Thanks again!